# netbeans 7.1.2, scala 2.9.1-1,nbscala-7.1v2.9.x-0.1.zip

Tags: java, scala, netbeans

Could you help me with this problem. I try to run scala file with simple code like "Hello,world", but there is error like this

```
C:\Users\Ersain\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ScalaApplication4\nbproject\build-impl.xml:403: **The following error occurred while executing this line**:
C:\Users\Ersain\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ScalaApplication4\nbproject\build-impl.xml:236: Problem: **failed to create task or type scalac
Cause: The name is undefined.**
```

I created user variable with this parameter: `SCALA_HOME,` value- `C:\scala-2.9.1-1\bin;`
system variable has  parameter like user variable

when I go to `TOOLS->SCALA PLATFORMS` it shows me this message

```
"Error: The specified folder does not contain a Scala platform.
If you want to specify a different folder for this platform, remove this platform and create a new one with exactly the same name pointing to the correct platform folder."
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `SCALA_HOME` to `C:\scala-2.9.1-1`, not the `bin` dir.