# How do I add the Scala Platform in Netbeans?

Tags: scala, ubuntu, netbeans, netbeans-7

I have installed a set of Scala plugins for netbeans, specifically:

Scala {Console, Project, Runtime Library, Platform, Platform Standard, Editor, Debugger Projects Integration, Refactoring, Debugger, Core} and Rats! Packrat Parser.  I have also installed scala via the ubuntu aptitude package manager.

When I go to Tools->Scala Platform Manager, I see "Scala 1.1 (Default)" in red, with the error: "Error: The specified folder does not contain a Scala platform."  I don't know how to correctly specify this.  I googled a bit, and it seems most people have compiled scala by hand, so they can specify their specific scala install directory.

`which scala` returns /usr/bin/scala, which I have tried in the Platform Folder option (as well as /usr/bin/).

The netbeans version is 7.0.1 and my scala version is "Scala code runner version 2.9.2 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL".  I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

Anyone know how to set Netbeans up to be happy with an aptitude installed Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried from aptitude, but it seems that you have not installed the scala plugin for Netbeans.

You should follow the instructions in https://github.com/dcaoyuan/nbscala

In particular beware to add the nbsbt plugin to your project definition, and run sbt. After that, start Netbeans, it  should recognise you project.

Comment: I'm trying this out now.  I did use this website which linked me to a plugins.netbeans.org page for the other plugins, but I may have been missing something.  I will report back when I have more information

Comment: Part of the problem was I got netbeans from the package manager, which was 7.0.1.  When I tried installing the plugins linked from your link (http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/54162) I didn't have new enough dependencies.  I'm reinstalling netbeans 8 from their installer.

Comment: I installed netbeans 8 and all the Scala plugins were available from the plugins list automatically.  I installed all of those plugins and now I'm back to the point where the "Scala Platform Manager" has the error: "Error: The specified folder does not contain a Scala platform."

Comment: I was able to solve this by installing scala from source, then by adding an option to netbeans_default_options in netbeans.conf.  I added -J-Dscala.home=$path  where $path is the path to my scala install.  This made netbeans find the scala install.  I'll upvote your answer, as it got me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I was trying to use Scala with netbeans: "Error: The specified folder does not contain a Scala platform.".
Solution is very easy, check it here: [netbeans 7.1.2, scala 2.9.1-1,nbscala-7.1v2.9.x-0.1.zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798412/netbeans-7-1-2-scala-2-9-1-1-nbscala-7-1v2-9-x-0-1-zip/14798477)

Comment: Please, include the relevant information regarding how to solve the problem in your answer. Links are good but they're not enough.

Comment: That link explains itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Project Properties : change Source/Binary Format to JDK 7
2. build-impl.xml : remove '-make:transitive' option in 'scalac addparams'
3. run Main Project

Answer (score 0):

As explain by Geertjan:

You can specify the scala platform by updating the netbeans_default_options in etc/netbeans.conf adding the following system property -J-Dscala.home pointing to you scala home directory, example:

netbeans_default_options="--laf Nimbus -J-Dscala.home=/home/geertjan/scala/scala-2.10.2 
-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true 
-J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true 
-J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"

It works for me.

Source: https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/10_steps_to_happiness_with