# Incorrect Scala plugin configuration for NetBeans 8?

Tags: scala, netbeans

I'm running NB 8.0.2 on Linux Mint 17.1. I've followed the instructions twice, but still only see the "Scala Sbt Project" project template. I was expecting to see several non-SBT templates as well. I can, however, create and run Scala objects just fine, so I can work with it as it is, even if I'm not planning on using SBT.

Is something wrong with my plugin config, though, if I'm only seeing the SBT project template?

I've already gone through [How do I add the Scala Platform in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702568/how-do-i-add-the-scala-platform-in-netbeans/) and other links, but this seems to be a NB 8 issue, as most of the posts/blogs concern NB 7 and 6.  I didn't see anything about it on https://github.com/dcaoyuan/nbscala or https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/10_steps_to_happiness_with .

Thanks,
Ari

Comment: Had the same issue in WIndows with Netbeans 8. It looks like everybody writes Java under Netbeans, not Scala...

Comment: Thanks for confirming that.