# how to use scala on netbeans (Windows)

Tags: scala, netbeans-8.1

I am a beginner in scala, I just installed it, but after installation I couldn't use it on netbeans, despite I have already integrated and I didn't find it  on my list of projects creation. any idea please[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9gRB.png)

Comment: Have a look at [how-do-i-add-the-scala-platform-in-netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702568/how-do-i-add-the-scala-platform-in-netbeans/23702839#23702839)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install the latest version of netbeans 8.2 giving in [this link](https://netbeans.org/downloads/), you can also use the [**Scala IDE**](http://scala-ide.org/?_ga=2.5920307.1837460913.1495451899-336637946.1495398047) or the [inteliJ IDEA IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) which have an integrated support for scala language

Please refer to the [official web site](https://www.scala-lang.org/) for more information

If you still want to use your version of Netbeans, it's very simple you just have to install the necessary plugins and the **scala** option will be one of list of choices when you create a new Project.

Hope this helps. Best Regrards

Comment: You tell the OP to install the "necessary" plugins. I believe that was exactly what he was asking for when he asked the question